# How to open Sticky Notes on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, sticky, stickynote

I would like to open Sticky notes without having to navigate to the location. In my research, I found that in Windows 7, users were able to type 'stikynot' in the run prompt. What is the equivalent of the prior information for Windows 10?

I looked at these sites but it requires me to create a shortcut and I want to avoid that option:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/starting-windows-10-store-app-from-the-command/836354c5-b5af-4d6c-b414-80e40ed14675

https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/57000-method-open-any-windows-10-apps-command-line.html

I was hoping something like this would work for Sticky Notes in the cmd:

```
start "" Calc.exe
start "" Notepad.exe
```

Comment: It seems that there is nothing. for your information. [10 ways to start Sticky Notes in Windows (all versions)](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/start-sticky-notes-windows)

Answer (score 4):

All you need is

```
explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

The ID doesn't change.

Comment: This is good, but for me it opens both a sticky note and a list of all other sticky notes.  I just want a new sticky note, not the list as well.

Comment: @Rob It just remembers the layout from when it was closed. If you want to open a new blank note, this can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Although your latter ([TenForums](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/57000-method-open-any-windows-10-apps-command-line.html)) link *seemingly* guides to a shortcut creation, you can use the final *command line* in a batch file instead as a shortcut target.

I have written the following PowerShell script `57498059.ps1` to automatise their (a bit complicated) guide:

```
Import-Module -Name 'Appx'
$StickyNotesName     = 'Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes'
$StickyNotesPack     = Get-AppxPackage -Name $StickyNotesName
$StickyNotesManifest = Join-Path -Path $StickyNotesPack.InstallLocation `
                            -ChildPath 'AppxManifest.xml'

$StickyNotesXml = New-Object Xml
$StickyNotesXml.Load("$StickyNotesManifest")

$StickyNotesExec = 'explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\' +
    $StickyNotesPack.PackageFamilyName + '!' + 
    $StickyNotesXml.Package.Applications.Application.Id

"@$StickyNotesExec" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath ".\stikynot.bat"
    # write `stikynot.bat` to a folder listed in Windows %path% variable
    # you can type `stikynot` in the run prompt or `cmd` prompt then

"$StickyNotesExec" # return value: cmd command to launch Sticky Notes 
Write-Host "$StickyNotesName - done"  -ForegroundColor Cyan

<# check if it works #>
    Invoke-Expression "$StickyNotesExec"
<##>
```

**Result** (and `Sticky Notes` app runs on *my* Windows 10):

```
PS D:\PShell> .\SO\57498059.ps1
```

> ```
> explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes - done
> ```

---

```
type .\stikynot.bat
```

> ```
> @explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> ```

Comment: On PowerShell 7,  you need `Import-Module -Name Appx -UseWIndowsPowershell`

Comment: Alternatively, if you aren't creating a shortcut, and just want to run it directly from powershell, you can use [Start-Process instead of Explorer.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46894243/10534510)

Answer (score 0):

Due to a new Windows Update the **old Sticky note** is removed from Windows 10.

You can restore the old feature by downloading [this zip File.(Contains the old program)](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/StikyNot.zip)

[The zip file contains no viruses. (Proof)](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/0da63fc2d8f11eed23642ed73f9815849f21cdf4ae917789683adb087d9e4d19/detection)

Here are the simple steps to restore the program.

0.5. Open the zip file

1. Locate `C:\Windows\System32` (Windows Key + r)
2. Copy and paste the `StikyNot.exe` in System32
3. Locate to `C:\Windows\System32\en-US`
4. Copy the file and paste `StikyNot.exe.mui` in `C:\Windows\System32\en-US`

Ta-da!

You can now use the file `StikyNot.exe` using

`start "" StikyNot.exe` in the .bat file

Regards,
Erik

Comment: One should generally not place programs into system32 at current user-trust levels - great way to get malware, even beyond general internet download installers.

Comment: Its virus-free. Here is a link to Virus Total https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/0da63fc2d8f11eed23642ed73f9815849f21cdf4ae917789683adb087d9e4d19/detection

Comment: I tried this. I don't see it in system32 though. If I try to paste it again, it says that the file already exists. But I can't see it.

Comment: In case of this works, it only will work for English (en-US) locale Windows installations. That mui file does not work for other folders like for example "es-ES".